# How to show wandb training progress from run folder

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, wandb

After training neural networks with wandb as the logger, I received a link to show the training results and a folder named "run-...", I assume that is the logging of the training process. Now I don't have that link, how to show the wandb training process from run folder?

Answer (score 1):

The run folder name is constructed as `run-<datetime>-<id>`.

You can find the logs on the UI platform *as long as you haven't yet deleted it online*. I'm not sure it is yet possible to resync the local copy to the cloud.

One way to find your run across projects is to go on your profile page: `https://wandb.ai/<username>` and type the run's *id* in the search bar.

[image]

Comment: What if I don't have the account? For now, I just need an interface to show logs on browsers like when I clicked on the link.

Comment: I don't think you can. You can always contact support, they will provide a more accurate answer and whether this can be done.